# How to list out all items in a nested table in Laravel 3

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel's Eloquent ORM and I need get all records in two tables.

- questionnaire
- question

Code:

```
class Questionnaire extends Eloquent
{
    public static $table = "questionnaire";

    public function question()
    {
        return $this->has_many('question', 'questionnaire_id');
    }
}
```

When I need make join I write this statement:

```
Questionnaire::find(1)->question()->get();
```

*Is this correct or not ?*

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: This isn't a join, this will run two separate queries, first for `find(1)` and second for `question()->get()`. To join in laravel3 you would use the Fluent interface that is available to all Eloquent models. You may also be interested to look into Eager Loading `Questionnaire::with('question', 'questionnaire_id')->find(1);`

Comment: --- And yes, you're statement is correct... does it work?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
class Questionnaire extends Eloquent
{
    public static $table = "questionnaire";

    public function questions() //table name = questions
    {
        return $this->has_many('question', 'questionnaire_id'); //model name of questions table: Question, questionnaire_id = matching column in the questions table
    }
}
```

And try using:

```
Questionnaire::with('questions')->find(1);
```